# Password protected XML-using-URL to Dataset, missing child node

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, datatable, dataset

I successfully loaded the password protected XML-using-Url(consuming a web service) to Dataset and to database using Linq to Dataset. The difficulty I am facing is one of the child node data is not retrieved from XML into ds/dt. 
On debug, I find three datatables(column names) - StuDet(Sid, stuExamId,name, StuGradeId, StCount_id); StCount(SId, year, semester, SubjectTypeId, markCount, StCount_id); SubjectTypeCode(SubjectTypeCode_Id, SubjectTypeId, SubjectTypeCode_Id_0,StCount_id)

Code to load XML using URL to Dataset:

```
Url = New Uri("http://exapmle.com/StudentFile.xml")
Dim creds As CredentialCache = New CredentialCache
creds.Add(Url, "Basic", New NetworkCredential("userId", "pwd"))
client.Credentials = creds
Dim strm As Stream = client.OpenRead(Url)
Dim strmRdr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strm)
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
ds.ReadXml(strmRdr)
```

Below is the xml data:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <StCounts>
- <StCount>
      <SId>3</SId> 
      <year>2014</year> 
      <semester>4</semester> 
      <SubjectTypeId>1</SubjectTypeId> 
      <markCount>95</markCount> 
    - <SubjectTypeCode>
          <SubjectTypeCode>Science</SubjectTypeCode> 
          <SubjectTypeId>1</SubjectTypeId> 
      </SubjectTypeCode>
    - <StuDet>
          <SId>3</SId> 
          <stuExamId>1234567890</stuExamId> 
          <name>Jon Snow</name> 
          <StuGradeId>0</StuGradeId> 
      </StuDet>
  </StCount>
- <StCount>
      <SId>3</SId> 
      <year>2014</year> 
      <semester>4</semester> 
      <SubjectTypeId>2</SubjectTypeId> 
      <markCount>50</markCount> 
    - <SubjectTypeCode>
          <SubjectTypeCode>Math</SubjectTypeCode> 
          <SubjectTypeId>2</SubjectTypeId> 
      </SubjectTypeCode>
    - <StuDet>
          <SId>3</SId> 
          <stuExamId>1234567890</stuExamId> 
          <name>Jon Snow</name> 
          <StuGradeId>0</StuGradeId> 
      </StuDet>
  </StCount>
- <StCount>
      <SId>3</SId> 
      <year>2014</year> 
      <semester>4</semester> 
      <SubjectTypeId>105</SubjectTypeId> 
      <markCount>80</markCount> 
    - <SubjectTypeCode>
          <SubjectTypeCode>History</SubjectTypeCode> 
          <SubjectTypeId>105</SubjectTypeId> 
      </SubjectTypeCode>
    - <StuDet>
          <SId>3</SId> 
          <stuExamId>1234567890</stuExamId> 
          <name>Jon Snow</name> 
          <StuGradeId>0</StuGradeId> 
      </StuDet>
</StCount>
</StCounts>
```

The column StCount_id, SubjectTypeCode_Id, SubjectTypeCode_Id_0 are autogenerated in the datatables.

I couldn't get the SubjectTypeCode (Science, Math, History) into the datatable SubjectTypeCode. Why is that? What am I missing?

Any help or lead would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No one ever got this issue?? :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the core problem. In the sample XML, see how the SubjectTypeCode is the parent and also the child. So I renamed the outer node to SubjectTypeCodes. Now the datatable is populating the SubjectTypeCode(Science, math, history) column.

Code that solved my issue:

```
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/StCounts/StCount")
        For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList
            Dim oldNode As XmlNode = node.SelectSingleNode("SubjectTypeCode")
            Dim newNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("SubjectTypeCodes")
            newNode.InnerXml = oldNode.InnerXml

            node.InsertBefore(newNode, oldNode)
            node.RemoveChild(oldNode)
        Next
```

The dataset now has a datatable with columns StCount_id, SubjectTypeCode_Id, SubjectTypeCode.

Answer (score 0):

- The only solution I can come up with  is to create a new data table
  with the SubjectTypeCode and SubjectTypeId.
- Add this datatable to the datatset.
- Join datatable to Query using Linq to DS

To quench the curiosity, I did test to see the SubjectTypeCode in SelectSingleNode. It was there.